# How can I run multiple statements using json array format for Docker ENTRYPOINT?

Tags: linux, docker

I need to set `ulimit` and `sysctl` before starting my service, so I have been doing the following in my `ENTRYPOINT`:

`ulimit -n 4096; sysctl -p; start_service`

But it seems that if I want to use `CMD` as default arguments to `ENTRYPOINT`, I have to use the json array format.

But I don't know how to run multiple statements using the json array format.

Comment: Which part of the command should take the default parameter(s) from CMD? `start_service`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Thanks for replying. You are right, I want parameters for the `start_service` part. So that I can choose what service to start when doing `docker run`.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is probably to execute it as a script (here start_service is replaced with a simple echo for testing)

```
$ cat start.sh
#!/bin/bash
ulimit -n 4096; sysctl -p; echo $@

$ cat Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu
COPY . /tmp
CMD ["test"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/tmp/start.sh"]

$ docker build -t test .
...

$ docker run test
test

$ docker run test "hello world"
hello world
```

Remember to `chmod 755 start.sh` before building the container or the script won't execute.